# MySQL PHP Verify an advert/post via email before displaying on website?

Tags: php, mysql

Working on a web based "buying and selling" application with PHP MySQL where users can post adverts for items and services.

Before a new advert is displayed on the system there must be a method of verification to ensure that the user provided email address is correct, and that the advert is legitimate.

I want to send the creator of any new advert an email containing an url which directs to a page whose primary functionality is to receive a posted variable, $advert_id, and to select the advert from the db for updating / editing / deleting.

This variable is embedded in the url with PHP syntax 
ie. [http://www.example.com?content=modify_advert&advert_id=2246317].

This part is quite simple to implement, BUT, if a user was to modify this variable called "advert_id=2246317" to any other integer, they can access other posts/adverts in the system.

The system is advert based, and users dont need an account or login to post, so we cannot prompt for a login at the point of verification which would have been convenient.

Any ideas as to how we could protect the adverts/posts in the system from being accessed via the aforementioned url???

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If visitors will only be viewing that page from the link you send via e-mail, you can include a **hash** in that address instead of the `advert_id` — essentially a random, one-time password.

One common and "often good enough" trick for generating such a random password is to take a single, secret, truly random string (I usually use [grc.com](https://www.grc.com/passwords.htm)), concatenate it with the unique advert_id, and hash the whole thing with, say, `SHA1()`.  Like so:

```
UPDATE advert SET advert_hash = SHA1(CONCAT(advert_id, 'lots-of-randomness-here'))
```

You could even vary this by adding `time()`, or (better still) a random number to the end.  The outcome is a 40-character string stored in your database that nobody could possibly predict (without knowing the secret data you used to generate it).

For example, I might get this instead of `advert_id=1`:

```
f2db832ddfb149522442c156dadab50307f12b62
```

If I wanted to sneakily edit `advert_id=2` (which somebody else created), I'd first have to *guess* that the hash is this *completely* different string:

```
e5c6a3a9473b814b3230ee7923cbe679fcebc922
```

So, include that in the URL instead of the advert_id (or, if you like, in addition to the advert_id), and suddenly your users are powerless to ruin other people's content.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) to the id and then hash it.

```
sha1($advert_id . $salt);
```

Send this to the user in the URL instead of the advert_id, and store it in your database, along with the advert_id.

Then when they click the link, you find the matching advert for that hashed value.

Making the salt a secret is how you keep users from 'guessing' a valid URL that will let them modify an ad that they did not post. Perhaps you could use the users email address, the time posted and/or a name or something that the user enters when they make a post.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a GUID as the advert ID so simple ID guessing attacks are unlikely to succeed.